# Linking to another section of code - java - beginner

Tags: java, netbeans, hyperlink, menu

I have a calculate button that operates perfectly according to my code.

I would like to execute the same code through a menu with file > calculate. Can I somehow reference the block of code and have that section executed or do I need to copy/paste?

I have a few more buttons that I am incorporating into the file menu as well, so I'd like to keep my code clean and minimal. Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Yes... you can. Place the code you have in your button's Action Performed event into a method named something like...perhaps...**calculate()**. Now in your button's Action Performed event use something like this single line: `calculate();`. Do the same for your menu selection event.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function you wrote for the calculate program when the file > calculate button is pressed.

Comment: Include your code and stacktrace in the original question